# Child div appear outside of parent div

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to replicate the azure portal design layout. The challenge that I'm facing, is once I'm inside of a component (in the image example "Virtual Machine") I need to ability to create a new component inside of it, but have the style appear that its a new panel in the main panel collection. Any ideas? I've provided a template pen below.

[image]

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/nickmuth/pen/xdXJmY)

```
<section id="panel-container">
  <div class="panel" style="border:1px solid red;"></div>
  <div class="panel" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="sub-panel" style="border:4px solid cyan;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless somebody can provide an alternative solution, this table hack is the best I can come up with. [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/nickmuth/pen/ybzwmg)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Panel</td>
    <td>Panel
      <td style="width: 600px;background:red;">Sub Panel</td>
      <td>Sub Sub Panel</td>
    </td>
    <td>Panel</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  min-width: 300px;
  height:100vh;
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a mix of `flexbox` and `position`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

#panel-container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.panel {
  flex: 0 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 4px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<section id="panel-container">
  <div class="panel"></div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="sub-panel"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I copied your code into a new pen, it doesn't seem to be producing the desired output. Am I missing something? The child panel should be next to its parent panel. I realized the arrow in my image may have been confusing, I was just trying to illustrate it was inside of its parent panel. https://codepen.io/nickmuth/pen/rmGqBo

Comment: I am confused of what are you trying to achieve. where you really want your `sub-panel`? inside the second `panel` or just next to the 2nd, like it was a 3rd `panel`?

Comment: This is very close to the desired output. The only piece I would be missing is the ability to add multiple sub-panels and have them not overlap but keep building out horizontally.

Comment: you would need to use JS to change `left` dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you should use `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: inline-block`.

```css
#panel-container {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sub-panel {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="panel-container">
  <div class="panel" style="border:1px solid red;"></div>
  <div class="panel" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="sub-panel" style="border:4px solid cyan;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: see above comments